# Finding the minimum and maximum value in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-clustering

I have a pandas dataframe from which clusters are created using

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata

tag_pos_refin = [(1042, 1056), (895, 922), (966, 995), (692, 716), 
                 (667, 690), (667, 690), (667, 690), (479, 508), (1112, 1578), 
                 (0, 29), (820, 835), (622, 635), (637, 642)]

max_dist = 500
clusters = fclusterdata(tag_pos_refin, t=max_dist, criterion='distance')

df = pd.DataFrame(tag_pos_refin, columns=['x', 'y'])
df["clusters"] = clusters
```

Then I am trying to find the minimum value from x and maximum value from y for each cluster. So the `expected output is in the form of list of tuples  [(1,479,1056),(2,1112,1578),(3,0,29)]` ----> `[(cluster,min,max)] format`

For this I used

```
df1 = df.groupby(['clusters','x']).size().groupby(level=0).idxmin().apply(lambda x: x[1]).reset_index(name='min')
df2 = df.groupby(['clusters','y']).size().groupby(level=0).idxmax().apply(lambda x: x[1]).reset_index(name='max')
```

One issue is this gives two different dataframes and has to merge and process again. Another issue is the output obtained is not same as the expected one. Obtained output has cluster 1 has maximum value as 690 but it has to be 1056.

How it can be obtained by a better way

Comment: does `df.groupby('clusters').agg([max,min])` give you what you want?

Comment: I am getting error with this `ValueError: no results` . Can you add in a bit more detailed way as answer.

Comment: What do you mean by error? what are the columns in your `df`? You should have three columns `x, y, clusters`. Then group by clusters and fincd the minimum and maximum eg does `df.groupby('clusters').min()` work for example?

Comment: This `df.groupby('clusters').min()` works but `df.groupby('clusters').agg([max,min])` gives error

Comment: what about `df.groupby('clusters').max()`

Comment: This also works. Actually i dont want min and max of both x and y. I just need only min from x and max from y

Comment: `df.groupby('clusters').agg({'x':min, 'y':max})`

Comment: if both the `min` and `max` methods work, then you have redefined the min or even max functions, consider removing the variables eg `del min` then `del max` whichever was defined will be removed and your code should now run